# This query not working this table, so how to update query this fornula with this table?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

**Table AAA**

```
k_id    main_id     keyword    click  price   click_time
    1     1         aaa         1     0.25    2017-11-05
    2     1         bbb         1     0.36    2017-11-05
    3     1         bbb         1     0.45    2017-11-05
    4     1         aaa         1     0.36    2017-11-05
    5     1         ccc         1     0.98    2017-11-05
    6     1         bbb         1     0.55    2017-11-05
    7     1         aaa         1     0.25    2017-11-05
    8     1         ccc         1     0.98    2017-11-05
    9     1         aaa         1     0.25    2017-11-05
    10    1         bbb         1     0.45    2017-11-05
```

**My query**

```
SELECT p1.keyword as keyword, 
SUM(
SELECT  sum(`click`) * price  FROM `AAA` p2 where main_id = '1' AND p2.keyword =  p1.keyword  AND DATE(p2.click_time) BETWEEN '2017-11-01' AND '2017-11-30' GROUP BY p2.price ORDER BY NULL
)                                       
as new1
FROM AAA p1
where p1.main_id = '1' AND DATE(p1.click_time) BETWEEN '2017-11-01' AND  '2017-11-30' 
GROUP BY p1.keyword
ORDER BY NULL LIMIT 0,20
```

Above query check so getting error this type

**You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT  sum(`click`) * cpc  FROM `AAA` p2 where main_id = '1' AND p2.ke' at line 3**

This query is right or not but this query also making another reference..!!

**Final result**

```
keyword     sum(click)    price

aaa         4           0.25 0.36 0.25 0.25 ( 0.36 * 1 + 0.25 * 3  )
bbb         4           0.36 0.45 0.55 0.45 ( 0.36 * 1 + 0.45 * 2 + 0.55 * 1 )
ccc         2           0.98 0.98           ( 0.98 * 2 ) 

original & final result getting this types 

keyword   price
aaa        0.86
bbb        1.81 
ccc        1.96
```

Comment: What you are trying to do? SUM within SUM?? Please clear

Comment: Yes ...Sum within sum but that sub query is also group vise cpc then multiple with sum of click that cpc ..

Comment: Main query is group of keyword and that all keyword getting total sum of subquery

Comment: Have you tried `sum(click * price)` instead of `sum(click) * price`

Comment: Please explain with query

Comment: Can you give your required output of the query as sample?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Ohk i will try explain my requirement

Comment: See this question @NigelRen

Comment: My suggestion is that your doing `sum(value) * otherValue`, try putting the multiplication inside the brackets so it's `sum(value*otherValue)`

Comment: Ohk try it @NigelRen

Comment: See return this question @krishnaaryal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have changed the query and made it as follows:

```
SELECT keyword,SUM(aa.eachSum) AS totalSum, SUM(aa.totalClicks) AS totalClicks FROM(
SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT p2.keyword) AS keyword,COUNT(p2.click) *  price AS eachSum, COUNT(p2.click) AS totalClicks
FROM `values_test` p2 WHERE main_id = '1'  AND DATE(p2.click_time) BETWEEN '2017-11-01' AND '2017-11-30' GROUP BY p2.price,p2.keyword
)aa GROUP BY aa.keyword
```

**Explanation**

```
SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT p2.keyword) AS keyword,COUNT(p2.click) *  price AS eachSum, COUNT(p2.click) AS totalClicks
FROM `values_test` p2 
WHERE main_id = '1'  
AND DATE(p2.click_time) BETWEEN '2017-11-01' AND '2017-11-30' 
GROUP BY p2.price,p2.keyword
```

This inner sub query collects distinct key word based on price and keyword because when you do group by only price then different keywords with same price get collected at one column which i guess is unwanted. This block results as follows:

```
keyword eachSum totalClicks
aaa      0.75     3
aaa      0.36     1
bbb      0.36     1
bbb      0.90     2
bbb      0.55     1
ccc      1.96     2
```

After collecting thsi data the outer query will group each keywords and sum the collect each values and output will be as follows:

```
keyword totalSum    totalClicks
aaa      1.11           4
bbb      1.81           4
ccc      1.96           2
```

And you have error in your sum example.
Please let me know if this is what you want.
(Note: i have changed the table name as per my use)

Comment: Thanks ..This is now getting correct results ..And i wrong AAA keyword calculation given you so sorry..

Comment: I edited query for total clicks too, if you need that!!

Comment: Also make this query of large data set and many column ...your edited query also making.... Thanks a lot

Comment: Hello ..when i tying with like in query so getting empty results .. @krishnaaryal